# Configure webpack to write to file and watch for changes

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, incremental-build

I have this webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {

  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './lib/index.js'],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist'),
    filename: 'suman.js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: ['latest'],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /(\/lib\/init\/|cli.js$)/,
        loader: 'ignore-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      fs: require.resolve('suman-browser-polyfills/modules/fs'),
      // assert: require.resolve('suman-browser-polyfills/modules/assert'),
      process: require.resolve('suman-browser-polyfills/modules/process'),
    },
    extensions: ['.js']
  }
};
```

as you can see Webpack is configured to write to a file, denoted by the "output" property in the configuration.

*However*, when I use webpack-dev-server, it will create a build, but it won't write it to the "output" file, it seems to just serve it to the browser.

What I am looking to do is have Webpack do incremental builds, but write to the file upon changes.

Comment: So to make it clear -  when running `webpack` it will write to the suman.js file, but when running `webpack-dev-server`, it won't write to the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack: How to compile, write on disk and serve static content (js/css) using webpack-dev-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928358/webpack-how-to-compile-write-on-disk-and-serve-static-content-js-css-using-w)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is simply to use `webpack --watch`, there is no need for me to use `webpack-dev-server` for my use case.