# workbox not picking up in-memory files with webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack-dev-server, workbox

In our project we are using webpack-dev-server to run our development environment.
We are currently transforming the project into a progressive-web-app using [workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/).

When we run webpack with NODE_ENV=production everything is working fine, as it first compiles the files, and then the workbox plugin picks them up and adds them to the service-worker.

When we run webpack-dev-server hot, the build fails when running the workbox plugin as it cannot find any files in the dist folder.

The problem seems to be that workbox is not picking up the js and css files that are generated in-memory and seems to need the files on the file system.

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'front'),
  entry: [
    ...preEntries,
    './react/app.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'front-dist'),
    filename: `react/app.${git.gitCommitAbbrev}.js`,
    chunkFilename: `react/[id].app.${git.gitCommitAbbrev}.js`,
    publicPath: '/glass/'
  },
  devtool: isProdEnv ? false : 'eval-source-map',
  stats: {
    chunkModules: false
  },
  module: {
    ...
  },
  plugins: [
    new WorkboxPlugin({
      globDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'front-dist'),
      globPatterns: ['**/*.{html,js,css,woff2}'],
      swDest: path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, 'front-dist/sw/'), 'service-worker.js'),
      handleFetch: true,
      clientsClaim: true,
      skipWaiting: true,
    })
  ]
}
```

Any idea's as to how this should be working

Comment: have u read https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/get-started/webpack?

Comment: They claimed to make it work with webpack-dev-server in this merge:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/pull/808
But I'm still having the same problem. If there's no build directory in the file system, it just doesn't work :(

Comment: As you pointed out it's because files are in memory not on disk, I believe this answer can help you here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928358/webpack-how-to-compile-write-on-disk-and-serve-static-content-js-css-using-w

Comment: Have you found a solution since then?

Answer (score 0):

Recent releases of `workbox-webpack-plugin` have support for in-memory filesystems, with [coverage in its test suite](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/3d02230f0e977eb1dc86c48f16ea4bcefdae12af/test/workbox-webpack-plugin/node/v4/generate-sw.js#L1047).

If you're still having troubles with the current release of Workbox, please [open an issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues) on the issue tracker and we can investigate further.

That being said, using a cache-first service worker inside of a hot-reload, local development environment is a puzzling choice, as caching defeats the purpose of seeing updates right away.