# Webpack devServer no output files generated?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5, webpack-config

I'm learning Webpack and trying the plugin `webpack-dev-server`. I'm learning by trying to change its settings in `webpack.config.js`.

#### Before change:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
},
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
  // ...
}
```

#### After change:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist/')
},
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
  open: true,
  // ...
}
```

#### The result:

- The `dist/` folder was not generated in my project folder.
- While the browser was still opened and serving the page with .js being applied.

So it seems like the `dist` folder is generated elsewhere? I'm also considering that it's because of my wrong settings of `output { path: ... }` or `devServer: { contentBase: ... }`.

btw, would `html-webpack-plugin` generate the output in a temporary folder if these two path settings were wrong?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936567/webpack-dev-server-does-not-place-bundle-in-dist

Answer (score 1):

### Question - Answer:

> So it seems like the dist folder is generated elsewhere? [...]

Yes. From one [GitHub thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1736#issuecomment-163875240):

> Please note that webpack-dev-server runs in memory by design. [...]

---

> I'm also considering that it's because of my wrong settings of `output { path: ... }` or `devServer: { contentBase: ... }`.

Yes. The `path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist/')` by the [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) will resolve to just `/dist`. Since it's at root directory you will be asked for the write-permission to do so.

**But**, since you're using `webpack-dev-server`, by default it will not generate files to the folder specified in your `output` - `path`.

#### Important point for people new to `node.js`:

> Prefer `path.join` than `path.resolve`.

Comparison:

```
path.join(__dirname, '/dist')
/* output: `/Users/path-to-your-project/dist`. */

path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist')
/* output: `/dist`. */
```

---

Here are some screenshots for trying make it clear:

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "webpack_practice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "build:watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch",
    "server": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack serve"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.49.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

**Test 1**: `npm run build`

[image]

**Test 2**: `npm run server`

[image]