# webpack 4 - webpack-dev-server is not creating file

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to bundle files with `webpack-dev-server`, everything is ok but dev-server is not changing any files, after save it's compiling files but not creating any files and not update them.

Also, I see it bundles files from node_modules and I see it ignores my exclude rule from `webpack.config.js`

**Config:**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
        filename: "out.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/')
                ],
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss?$/,
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
                ],
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',

            },
            {
                test: /\.html?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        attrs: [':data-src']
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
```

I use **npm start** and console shows me this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, `webpack-dev-server` saves the changes in memory and serves it from there, physically you will not find the changed files on your system. If you want them to build then use `npm run build` and pass the necessary options to `webpack` which will output the build files

See here for a [complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928358/webpack-how-to-compile-write-on-disk-and-serve-static-content-js-css-using-w/41928812#41928812)