# Acces files from webpack dev server

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm looking for the location of the files (bundles) that the webpack dev server use to send to the browser, but apparently, they magically are accessible by the browser and they are no where to be found! Please help me resolve this mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, webpack dev server doesn't actually write files, it servers then in response to http requests. You can use the `writeToDisk` option if you want webpack to actually write the files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944885/11145447.

Comment: But how does webpack doing this without writing the files? Can you go more in depth @programmerRaj

Comment: It is not working with the latest webpack

Comment: @jaapklaas When your browser sends a GET request to the server, webpack compiles / retreives from memory the code to serve, and sends it to the browser. Everything is kept in memory.